# Is it possible to change product quantity automatically depending on total price or total weight?

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I am using Extra Product Options & Add-Ons for WooCommerce plugin. Which is allowing me to set quantity depending on custom field selection. But this custom field quantity selection is not reducing the total quantity from main product.

So i am looking for automatically implement the quantity based on total price or total weight. Because custom field is allowing to add weight addition based on custom field setup.

I have tried using variable product but that is not working for me because i am using a conditional pricing on the single product page. So if i do use cumulative sum of total for variable product its not working for me.

Also tried using event type other add ones but its not working.